# How does instancing improve render times with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, instances, performance, hardware

I can understand why instancing reduces the amount of memory used since you don't duplicate the polygons of your scene, you simply reference them from multiple locations in the scene.

From a technical/hardware point of view (because I guess that's what it's going to come down to), how does it improve render times though? As long as you're not running out of memory **without** instancing, it shouldn't change anything?

Is it because instancing allows for a better use of the CPU/GPU cache since the exact same memory locations are accessed?

Comment: To my poor understanding, reading and loading/unloading data takes time. Calling for a new data load takes time. So the bigger and numerous you have, the more time it takes.

Comment: Forgot to mention: when rendering animation, data is loaded at the beginning of each frame, unless you enable [persistant data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html?highlight=persistent+data#final-render) which will load data only at the first frame but at the cost of a longer first-load time, memory overflow, and historically had some data corruption issues sometimes.

Comment: @L0Lock Makes sense. Maybe instancing doesn't improve render times "explicitly" in the end but only "implicitly" thanks to the reduction of data transfers. I can't really test it myself on a Blender scene unfortunately, I'm not that good of a Blender user...

Comment: Imagine yourself ordering printing paper online. Do you prefer to make 1 order of 100 pages, or 100 orders of 1 page? Also you pay the same amount of delivery fee per order.